# What is the proper way of checking JWTs from 2 different servers in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Let's use this picture as a demo

[image]

So I have 2 node apps. One is where I have the login pages etc., and 2 is the API server with JWT as security layer.

Currently, the first server is only for rendering client pages. I have a login page, and the route where the login process goes is in the server with JWT.

My problem is that I want to check my token if it's valid before rendering the login page. So I must do that in the first server.

What is the proper way of doing this? Can I install express session in my first server to store the token from the second server? In that way, I can send a request from the first server to the API server before rendering client pages.

Comment: I don't understand it. Where does the token get generated? Are there 2 tokens? Why would you need a token to see the login page? Don't you need to login to get a token?

Comment: @fafl, I have 2 servers right. The one without the token and the other has. So the login page is in the server without the token. What I'm currently doing now is to store the jwt in the session of the server without token.

Comment: Since I'm the only one who responded, you'll have to deal with me being slow :D I don't understand what "a server has a token" means. Does the server generate or validate the token?

Comment: I think that you should do the following:
1. Let the first server check if there is a token in the headers (this way you save one call to the other server).

2. If there is a token but the second server is the only that can verify them, send a request from the first server to the second and wait for the results.

3. If everithing went okay, let the first server send the response that corresponds to the case. If not, just deny the access.

I dont know if this is the best way to doit, because it requires a lot of calls, but it may solve the problem.

Comment: Are you're using Server Side Rendering and want to make some request to the JWT protected Server in order to render some HTML before you send back the response to the Client? When using Client request, you can send request directly to JWT Server wit the token. But with SSR, when Browser ask for the URL directly, the Server won't find the JWT in Browser's Local Storage, so I suppose you could put the JWT into session, so that anytime Browser requests a URL, the Server for rendering will find the JWT token in the session, and you can pass the token from the Server to the JWT Server.

Comment: I personally wouldn't check if JWT is active on the Normal Server. I would make the Request to JWT Server passing the token from Normal Server's session, and then the JWT Server would verify if the token is active. If active, then JWT Server responds with the content and the Normal Server would serve the page back to the Client. If token is not active, let JWT Server refreshes token OR responds with a server CODE that says the token is expired. Then the Normal Server would redirect to or serve the Login page instead.

Comment: "Can I install express session in my first server to store the token from the second server?" Yes you can. I think you have 2 choices there: 1) Put express session on both Normal Server and JWT Server. 2) Put express session on Normal Server and save JWT token in Client Local Storage. Because I think you should avoid making Ajax calls on browser to the Normal Server to free your Normal Server, Client Async calls should be made directly on the JWT Server to get additional data needed. The 1st option can be used with Browser only. The second can be used with Browser and any other Client type.